# Is there a hot key that will allow me to move to an adjacent tab in internet browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer, browser-tabs

I'm currently using IE, but I have Chrome and Firefox as well. I use keyboard shortcuts a lot, especially when switching inbetween windows. I was wondering if it was possible for any of those browsers to have a keyboard shortcut to switch between tabs, instead of having to click on each one.

So, what are some keyboard shortcuts that make getting around in a browser easier? I know a few like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> (switch to next tab over) and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (close current tab).

Comment: No offence but -1 for no research effort....
The answer was just a google search away..

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Is there a way I Can open the previously opened tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Adding to previous answers:**

Chrome can switch tabs using numbers.
e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> will get you to 1st tab and so on..

**Added info:**
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> opens new tab
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> closes current tab
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> opens last closed tab(Pressing <kbd>T</kbd> N times will open the last N tabs)
Middle-click a link to open it in new tab
Middle click tab to close it.

In Chrome, you can select tabs using standard <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys(as with files in Explorer) and pull them out in a new window.

Comment: Using numbers we can switch upto 9 tabs only. If there is more than 9 tabs, numbers till 8 only can be used. And ctrl+9 will take you to the last tab. We can't access the intermediate tabs.

Comment: quite true..
but still a handy feature..
if you want to jump to 10th tab from 1st, instead of pressing Ctrl+Tab  9 times, we can jump to 8th and then go to 10th..

Comment: I just saw this and tried ctrl-<number> on Firefox (24.0) and it works.  Very nice -- better than tabbing all the way up and down one at a time.

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will let you switch between tabs.

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> – Switch to the next tab – in other words, the tab on the right. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd> also works, but not in Internet Explorer.)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> – Switch to the previous tab – in other words, the tab on the left. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> also works, but not in Internet Explorer.)

More common browser shortcuts can be [found here](http://www.howtogeek.com/114518/47-keyboard-shortcuts-that-work-in-all-web-browsers/)

Comment: It's not always tab on left/right. Some browsers go to through in different orders, like which ones you used last etc.

Comment: @Svish You are correct. I just added as this is followed in mostly used browsers.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by others <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> allows you to switch between tabs.
On firefox I use [mouseless browsing](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/mouseless-browsing/) addon to browse using keyboard. You may want to have a look at that.